# Nginx ingress controller doesn't accept encoded characters in URL

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, special-characters, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My ingress controller doesn't work when there are encoded characters in the URL.

So, for an endpoint with a path variable like this:

```
GET /api/v2/products/<<product_name_path_variable>>/aggregate
```

the call below with a path value with no encoded/special character works fine:

```
https://myhost.domain.com/myservice/api/v2/products/androidphone/aggregate
```

But the call below returns back 404 (Not Found) even though "android/phone" exists:

```
https://myhost.domain.com/myservice/api/v2/products/android%2Fphone/aggregate
```

The same with escaping with back slash

**I changed the service type to NodePort to expose it to the out of the cluster and it worked fine with the encoded forward slash when I reached out to the service directly and not through the ingress controller.**

Here's my ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: myReleaseName
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: myNameSpace
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-17T16:28:56Z"
  generation: 25
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myInstance
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: my-service
    helm.sh/chart: my-service-1.0.12
  name: my-service
  namespace: myNameSpace
  resourceVersion: "110955674"
  uid: 7e1fc6fb-77ab-41fa-9a32-76c7f1a078e9
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              name: http
        path: /myservice(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.domain.com
    secretName: myhost.domain.com-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.20.30.40
```

I saw this [open defect](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5576) but was thinking **maybe we can update the path, add another one, update the rewrite-target or add use-regex or a configuration-snippet** to make it accept encoded/escaped special characters like a forward slash. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if the special character "\" can be used like "android\/phone" and also using a new path in the ingress controller for only this scenario.

Comment: @KiranKotturi, "\" also doesn't work to escape the forward slash. What would you suggest for the other path to add to cover escaping?